# How to data add in List<Object> items in android

Tags: java, android

I am a new android developer.I am developing a sample application .I want to add some data in a object list.

My MainActivity.java class code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private PersonalInfo item;
private List<PersonalInfo> itemList = new ArrayList<PersonalInfo>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        item.setFirstName("AA::" + i);
        item.setLastName("BB::" + i);
        item.setAddress("New City " + i);
        item.setSex("Male");
        itemList.add(item);
        item = new PersonalInfo();
    }
    for(PersonalInfo p:itemList){
        System.out.println("First Name::"+p.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Last Name::"+p.getLastName());
    }

}

}
```

My PersonalInfo.java class code:

```
public class PersonalInfo {

 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;
 private String address;
 private String sex;

 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }
 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
 public String getLastName() {
   return lastName;
 }
 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
 public String getAddress() {
  return address;
 }
 public void setAddress(String address) {
   this.address = address;
 }
 public String getSex() {
   return sex;
 }
 public void setSex(String sex) {
   this.sex = sex;
 }  

}
```

When I run it ,then show flowing error
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: create new instance of item Variable then set the other thing to it, u must create new instance in your for statement and before set anything t it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

problem is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        item.setFirstName("AA::" + i);  <-- error happened here because item is null
        item.setLastName("BB::" + i);
        item.setAddress("New City " + i);
        item.setSex("Male");
        itemList.add(item); 
        item = new PersonalInfo();
    }
```

you need first initialize `item` then set data to that, so your code must be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            item = new PersonalInfo();  <-- I've moved this line
            item.setFirstName("AA::" + i);
            item.setLastName("BB::" + i);
            item.setAddress("New City " + i);
            item.setSex("Male");
            itemList.add(item);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks this really helpful. But could you please explain as to why we need to reinitialize it each time in the loop.

Comment: @gaurav4sarma call by reference issue, if you don't initialize in loop you change one instance each time, as your list items point to reference of object, all item changes to last item. if it's not clear yet tell me to explain more

Comment: I got it sorry for missing out on such a major small detail @shayan

Answer (score 2):

change your for loop too this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        item = new PersonalInfo();  // line1
        item.setFirstName("AA::" + i);
        item.setLastName("BB::" + i);
        item.setAddress("New City " + i);
        item.setSex("Male");
        itemList.add(item);

    }
    for (PersonalInfo p : itemList) {
        System.out.println("First Name::" + p.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Last Name::" + p.getLastName());
    }
```

Your problem is in `Line1` : You can't insert values to a object without creating it. So you have to create the object first and then initialize its attributes.

Comment: Are you sure size of list is Always 5? maybe OP set that to 5 just for test, so use Array is not suitable, and as I said in my answer initializing line is problem, so don't need change list to array

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Is this change acceptable? we can change the size using the count variable.

Comment: why you don't use List? this solution work just for fixed size.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan I got your point, Is this edit acceptable? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You just need to new an instance of PersonalInfo;
Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    item = new PersonalInfo();  <-- I've moved this line
    item.setFirstName("AA::" + i);
    item.setLastName("BB::" + i);
    item.setAddress("New City " + i);
    item.setSex("Male");
    itemList.add(item);
}
```